# Toggle login logout not working in react js, when we refresh page then it is not working (means Navbar Components not changing)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

If we press login, and do log in process successful then login button remove from Navbar and Log out button displayed but problem is that when we press log out then log out working successfully but after pressing logout still logout is there in Navbar instead of showing Login (If we refresh then working properly)

Comment: please include code which constitutes a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what code have you written just follow below approach:

First create a state(default value false) as shown below:

```
let [authenticated, setauthenticated]= React.useState(false);
```

when your user successfully logged in then just update that state to true as shown below:

```
setauthenticated(true)
```

In JSX just check if the user is authenticated the show them Logout component otherwise signup/login according to your requirement

```
{authenticated ? <Logout/> : <Signup/> }
```